# connect to mdf data base from java

Tags: java, database

I created an mdf data base file in visual studio 2010
 is there any way to connect to this data base from java netbeans project
I find a jdbc driver but it didn't work

Comment: Some quick Googling tells me that a MDF database is a SQL Server Express database.  There are also results out there (not all on SO) for connecting to them - what have you tried and what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot work directly with the MDF file from Java.  You will need to have a database program instance open on the MDF file, which you then can talk to through JDBC if the database program instance has a JDBC driver available.

If all you need is a simple database for your Java program, then look into Apache Derby which can be embedded in your application.

Comment: what do you mean by "database program instance"

Comment: what do you mean by "database program instance" 
do you mean i shoud open the file with ex.(sql server 2008) then I can talk to the data base using JDBC driver